# Worker asked to create wait channel was in stopped state

Tags: shiny

I'm a regular user of shinyapps.io.  I've recently been getting the following behaviour intermittently:

1) grey screen + 'disconnected from the server... reload'
2) reload, and get An error has occurred... Worker asked to create wait channel was in stopped state.

Wait a while... (1min? 3mins? not sure exactly) and it reloads ok.
Disconnected from the server.
I don't think I am doing anything radically different from previously, but googling this error message gives me only one hit here: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shinyapps-users/AMROjcib8DA

I cannot replicate the problem locally.  I cannot find a set of clicks on the webpage that repeatably generates the error.  I don't believe it is using really a lot of memory - locally running memory.size(max=F) returns 76.26.

I am using R version 3.4.0., I have Windows 7 and I'm using the free account on shinyapps.io

Any help very welcome.  Thanks!